# Circle-ci how to enter keystore information to use a custom keystore instead of the default

Tags: android, calabash, circleci, calabash-android

I am integrating calabash-android test on CircleCI. Everything has been working fine so far in my local. When I started building the test on CircleCI getting the below response

```
Please enter keystore information to use a custom keystore instead of the default

Please enter keystore location command calabash-android setup took more than 10 minutes since last output.
```

Attaching the circle.yml file below.

```
machine:
environment:
  ANDROID_HOME: /usr/local/android-sdk-linux
  JAVA_HOME: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64

ruby:
  version: 2.2.0

#general:
 #   artifacts:
 #      - /home/ubuntu/Latto-Android/app/build/outputs/apk/      

dependencies:
  cache_directories:
  - ~/.android
  - ~/android
override:
  - gem install calabash-android

test:
  pre:
    - emulator -avd circleci-android22 -no-audio -no-window:
      background: true
      parallel: true

override:
  - echo "Running JUnit tests!!!!!!" && ls && pwd
  - circle-android wait-for-boot
  - sleep 5
  # Unlock the emulator device
  - fb-adb shell input keyevent 82
  - sleep 5
  - fb-adb shell input touchscreen swipe 370 735 371 735
  - sleep 5
  - calabash-android setup
  - calabash-android resign "Test-debug-unaligned.apk"
  - calabash-android run "Test-debug-unaligned.apk" -v
```

I have tried different methods to fix the issue but the issue still exist. All kinda helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Store your keystore file in private dropbox folder. Save the link to download the file as a environment variable ($KEYSTORE_DOWNLOAD_URL). Create a shell script inside your .circleci folder named download.sh as below:-

```
    if [[ ${KEYSTORE_DOWNLOAD_URL} ]] then

        curl -L -o KEYSTORE_FILE_NAME ${KEYSTORE_DOWNLOAD_URL} else
        echo "No keystore Environment variable found" 
    fi
```

Add a step in the config as below:-

```
sh .circleci/download.sh
```

I hope this helps you :)

Comment: Wow, You are little late brother. Thanks for the help anyway.